# How to change transparency of background image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an repeating opaque background for an element. I need to be able to change the opacity for the background image using javascript. I want to adjust the image opacity based on scroll position.

I found this link to do it using css "after" pseudo class: [Css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/)

But it looks like I cannot change properties for pseudo classes using javascript.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:
HTML:

```
<div id="img"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#img{background:url(enter your image file url here); width:100%; height:100%;}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("img").style.opacity=0.5;
```